# Why is PooledOLS in Python giving me the error 'dependent and exog must have the same number of observations' when they are the same length?

Tags: python, pandas, linearmodels

I'm using Panel OLS from linearmodels to run the following regression

```
reg_1 = PooledOLS(y_endog, X_1).fit(cov_type = 'heteroskedastic')
```

but get an error message saying that the endogenous and exogenous variables aren't the same length.

```
if y.shape[0] != x.shape[0]:
--> 415             raise ValueError(
    416                 "dependent and exog must have the same number of " "observations."
    417             )

ValueError: dependent and exog must have the same number of observations.
```

However, if I check the shape of both `y_endog` and `X_1` they are the same shape. I also ensure there are no NaN values by dropping any rows and resetting the index prior to creating the `y_endog` and `X_1` dataframes.

If I run the code where the number of columns in `X_1 = 1` the estimation works. However as soon as `X_1` has more than 1 column the estimation no longer works (e.g. adding an additional variable to the PooledOLS model).

**DataFrames**:

`y_endog`:

[image: y_endog]

`X_1`:

[image: X_1]

Comment: Can you open an issue on the linearmodels tracker?  I think you probably should have a multiIndex but this error message isn't helpful.